# Question about 2 rxjs observables and a timer

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

I have a question about rxjs in the context of nestjs CQRS sagas.

Suppose I have a scenario where there is two events being published one after another one. One sets the value and the other one unsets it. I need to be able to listen to the event which sets the value for 3 seconds and perform some action if another event has not been published in the meantime.

Here is some code for starters:

```
valuePersisted = (events$: Observable<any>): Observable<ICommand> => {
return events$
  .pipe(
    ofType(ValueHasBeenSet),
    map(event => {
      return new SomeCommand();
    }),
  );
}
```

I need to listen to `ValueHasBeenUnset` event somehow and cancel out of the stream in case this event was received within some time.

EDIT

I just realized that events `ValueHasBeenSet` and `ValueHasBeenUnset` can have different value types to be set and unset and code should distinguish that. For example both events have a property called `type` and its value can be `'blue' | 'yellow'`. Is there a way to preserve the logic per event type keeping only two generic events `ValueHasBeenSet` and `ValueHasBeenUnset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider implementing it in the following way:

```js
 return events$
  .pipe(
    ofType(ValueHasBeenSet), // <- listen for ValueHasBeenSet event
    switchMap(x => {  // <- use switchMap to return a timer 
      return timer(3000).pipe(
        takeUntil(events$.pipe(ofType(ValueHasBeenUnset))), // <- unsubscribe from the timer on ValueHasBeenUnset event
        map(event => {
          return new SomeCommand(); // <- map to SomeCommand once 3 seconds have passed
        })
      )
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works for a single event type. I updated the question with a bit more complicated use case.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Just need to add `filter` operator in the second observable so that it takesUntil based on the even type.